# Where can i upload the audio file to convert it into text using Google Cloud?

Tags: google-speech-api, google-text-to-speech

I have singed-up in Google-Cloud-Speech To text. Now i want text the audio files, since it has given 60 minutes free trail.

Would you please let me know where can i upload the audio files on google-cloud-speech-To-Text.

Answer (score 0):

For [long audio files](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize), these needs to be uploaded in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) to use the Cloud Storage URL in the Speech-to-Text API request.

Hope it helps.